How to Replace Patterns in URLs with SQL using Clickhouse?
I'm working with a table that has a 'url' field, and I need to replace specific patterns if they exist in each URL. Here is an example of my table:
| url                         |
|-----------------------------|
| url-1.html                  |
| url-2.html                  |
| url-3.html?q=my+string-1    |
| url-3.html?q=my+string-2    |
| url-4.html?q=other-string   |
| url-4.html?q=no-string      |

I have the following patterns to replace:

text1 --> textone
my+string --> mystringReplaced
other+string --> otherstringReplaced

I'm trying to accomplish this using SQL with the following query:
WITH
['text1', 'my+string', 'other+string'] AS replaced,
['textone', 'mystringReplaced', 'otherstringReplaced'] AS substitute,
['url-1.html', 'url-2.html', 'url-3.html?q=my+string-1', 'url-3.html?q=my+string-2', 'url-4.html?q=other-string', 'url-4.html?q=no-string'] AS urls
SELECT
FinalURL.2 as FinalURL
FROM
(
    SELECT
        arrayMap((x, y) -> if(positionCaseInsensitive(urllTemp, x) > 0,(x, replaceAll(urllTemp,replaced[toInt64(y)],substitute[toInt64(y)])),(urllTemp,urllTemp)),replaced,range(1, length(replaced) + 1)) AS FinalURL
    FROM
    (
        SELECT arrayJoin(urls) AS urllTemp
    )
)
 FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNames

Results for this SQL:



FinalURL




['url-1.html','url-1.html','url-1.html']


['url-2.html','url-2.html','url-2.html']


['url-3.html?q=my+string-1','url-3.html?q=mystringReplaced-1','url-3.html?q=my+string-1']


['url-3.html?q=my+string-2','url-3.html?q=mystringReplaced-2','url-3.html?q=my+string-2']


['url-4.html?q=other+string','url-4.html?q=other+string','url-4.html?q=otherstringReplaced']


['url-4.html?q=no-string','url-4.html?q=no-string','url-4.html?q=no-string']



View this SQL in Fiddle
This query should produce the desired result:
| FinalURL                          |
|-----------------------------------|
| url-1.html                        |
| url-2.html                        |
| url-3.html?q=mystringReplaced-1   |
| url-3.html?q=mystringReplaced-2   |
| url-4.html?q=otherstringReplaced  |
| url-4.html?q=no-string            |

Can someone explain why this works and if there's a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

This query works....
with
    ['text1',
    'my+string',
    'other+string'] as replaced,
    ['textone',
    'mystringReplaced',
    'otherstringReplaced'] as substitute,
    ['url-1.html',
    'url-2.html',
    'url-3.html?q=my+string-1',
    'url-3.html?q=my+string-2',
    'url-4.html?q=other+string',
    'url-4.html?q=no-string'] as urls
    select
    URL 
    from
        (
        select
            arrayMap((x,y) -> if(positionCaseInsensitive(urllTemp,x) > 0,(y,replaceAll(urllTemp,replaced[toInt64(y)],substitute[toInt64(y)])),(NULL,urllTemp)),
            replaced,
            range(1,
            length(replaced) + 1)) as FinalURL,
            arrayFilter(y->(y>1 and y is not null),arrayMap(x->indexOf(FinalURL,x),FinalURL)) as comprs,
            if(length(comprs)>0,FinalURL[comprs[1]],FinalURL[1]).2 as URL
        from
            (
            select
                arrayJoin(urls) as urllTemp
        )
    )
     FORMAT TabSeparatedWithNames

View Fidle
